# Send data from textarea to SharePoint list with javascript

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online, list-item

I have created a SharePoint app for a form with textarea boxes. Now I want to send all data that I have written in the textarea to SharePoint with javascript.

Every textarea have a unique ID and I have a list in SharePoint with columns where I want my data to be stored.

How can I connect my textarea boxes with my columns in my list?

Comment: What kind of app? Provider or SharePoint-hosted? I want to assume SharePoint since you are using JavaScript. And where is the list? The host or the app web? If on the host the cross-domain library will be required.  Other than that, it's simply retrieving the value from the textarea and using either JSOM or REST to submit the data.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
function setItems() {

var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(), listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);

listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment', $('#GEN_1').val()); 
listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment_D', $('#GEN_1_D').val());
listItem.set_item('GEN_2_CRMname', $('#GEN_2').val());
listItem.set_item('GEN_2_CRMname_D', $('#GEN_2_D').val());
listItem.update();

appContext.load(listItem);
appContext.executeQueryAsync(function (success) { alert("Din sparning lyckades!"); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });
}
```